# УдилА или удИла?

Tags: фонетика

Когда я занималась конным спортом, мы всегда говорили исключительно "удилА". Но насколько это правильно?
Точно также чучельники всегда говорят "чучелА", а не "чУчела". Это профессиональный жаргон?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

удилА - это правильное ударение, а Ваш пример с чучелами отражает профессиональный сленг

Answer (score 3):

УдилА и удИла - это разные вещи.

УдилА - часть сбруи, удИла - множественное к "удило" - устаревший вариант слова удилище, иногда используемый в профессиональной речи рыбаков.

С множественным для "чучело" возникают некоторые сложности в связи с отсутствием подходящих употребительных моделей. Я так и не вспомнил подходящего слова среднего рода из трех слогов, с ударением на первом ("золото" не имеет множественного числа). Но все-таки причин для перенесения ударения на флексию я не вижу. Поэтому - чУчела.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от контекста слово "удИла" вообще может быть глаголом в прошедшем времени.